# Title column not updating using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I am trying to migrate a list from SP2010 to SP2013. The list is created with its default column `Title`. But when I try to update this list with some value in title column, it shows that it has been done in code but when I see in list, there is no item added.

Also if I create any other column and update it using csom, it is able to create new items but problem is with the title column.

Comment: Can you add some code here ?

Answer (score 1):

Verify 'Title' field's internal name. And this name must match with the column name which is used in the query via CSOM.